# "XXXX\wpf.war does not exist, files not copied" error in IBM Portlet factory application

Tags: portlet

When i tried to use the existing application which was working good in some days back, now throwing error as "factory dev war location XXXX\wpf.war does not exist, files not copied".  I am using IBM websphere 6.1, Portal server 5.1. Anybody can help me ?

Comment: Are you really using WAS 6.1 with Portal 5.1 or is that a typo? Anyway, what do the logs say? Is that the entire error message or does it say anything else?

Comment: clear your project space, and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any Web Experience Factory (current name, 7.0.1 through 8.0.0.x) or WebSphere Portlet Factory (old name, version 7.0 and earlier) versions that are still supported for Portal 5.1, so as the above comment suggests, hopefully that's a typo?  If so, please update the post with the actual version of portal.

That message typically means that it cannot locate the deployed WAR from the Eclipse based Designer development environment, so it cannot auto-synch files updated in Eclipse/Designer with the deployed development WAR.   Again, there's no version currently supported for such an old portal version, so please verify whether you're developing a new app in Eclipse/Designer or just trying to keep an old app running.   If the latter, then you shouldn't be using Designer or a development WAR, so it's unclear what you're doing that's causing the error.  If the former (developing the application), then I strongly suggest getting on a currently supported version of Web Experience Factory / Portal combination.

I hope that info helps,
..Mike Burati 
The postings on this site are my own and do not necessarily represent the positions, strategies, or opinions of IBM.